# Python – validate input is real folder and not root

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, validation, command-line-arguments

I'm writing a script in Python. The user has to enter a folder for the scrip to run on. There is some copying and moving of files and at a certain point a folder will be deleted. So, under no circumstances do I want this script to be run on the root folder. (or current or parent for that matter)

So I need to validate this. But how do I do that since "/" “./” “.” “..” etc .. as input are all perfectly valid and existing folders using os.path.isdir().

Should I manually check the input for these system folder symbols. Or is there a better way (existing function perhaps?) to check if the input is a real existing folder, but not a  system or symbolic folder like (root, current, parent, etc …)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to *normalize* your path by making it absolute. You probably also want to eliminate symbolic links:

```
import os.path

normalized = os.path.realpath(os.path.absolute(path))
if normalized == '/':
    raise ValueError("Can't use root as a destination")
```

Making a path absolute eliminates any current or parent path references, as well as any doubled separators.

Answer (score 1):

Either forbid '..' in paths or use [abspath](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath) to get the real path.